# Create the largest subset sum

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, binary, dynamic-programming

We have an array representing segment lengths. Our objective is to find the largest possible value for which you can create subsets of these segments, each totaling the same value. It's not necessary to utilize every segment provided. The number of subsets is 4.

Comment: Hi there. Well, you already gave it the dynamic programming tag, so I'd play around with that approach for a bit until you hit a concrete block.

Comment: Hi! I tried basing a solution from this example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-maximum-subset-sum-formed-by-partitioning-any-subset-of-array-into-2-partitions-with-equal-sum/ but it just doesn't really seem to work :/ any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use that solution and adjust it so that instead of partitioning into two partitions, you partition into four (one for each side).

Comment: Array size and value range are important here

Comment: Can you show some sample examples?